# How to resolve HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action org.name.action.TutorialAction and result?

Tags: java, struts2

I was writing an struts 2 project in eclipse.After starting the project on tomcat server, whenever i insert this url : **http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action** on web browser then the browser dispalys this error: **HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action org.name.action.TutorialAction and result**

am i missing any other important jer files? or  Do i need to add convention-plugin-2.3.x.jar ? or Do i need to add annotation ?

These are the the jer files i added in WEB-INF/lib :

```
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.22.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struts2-core-2.3.24.jar
xwork-core-2.3.24.jar
```

this is struts.xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">        
 <struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">       
    <action name="getTutorial" class="org.name.action.TutorialAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
 </struts>
```

this is TutorialAction class code below:

```
package org.name.action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TutorialAction  extends ActionSupport{

    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("Hello From execute() method.");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

this is web.xml code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>      
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

under this folder given image  ,i added my jsp pages:
[image]

Updates: during cleaning the project this error was occurred :

```
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'Struts2Starter'. Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/Java8} Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/Java8}
```

is this the main reason or other things needed.how to solve this. 
 please let me know for further information.

Comment: Turn dev mode on and check your server startup logs.

Comment: Where have you placed `success.jsp`?

Comment: success.jsp is  inside web folder

Comment: and result is missing

Comment: so in that case what can i do .where to add this result.thanks

Comment: You're saying the JSP page is at the root level of your web content?

Comment: i edited a screenshot where i store all the jsp pages.take a look please.thanks

Comment: @user5005768 The result should have a name, if it doesn't have a name you can't add it.

Comment: @RomanC sorry i didn't understand result name. are you talking about this code: **<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
  <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>**

Comment: these results have a name

Comment: @RomanC yes these results have a name. am i doing wrong.should i remove names? thanks

Comment: @user5005768 No, everything ok with the results except that you might be missing some result, but if you do it then the name of the result should be in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the value returned from `execute()` method resolves to an empty String. Check if you have local/class/instance variable with name `SUCCESS` which has value of empty String.

If there is a result name being returned and if the result is not found, Struts gives error with result name. For e.g., the result `success` is being removed and it gives error `HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action org.name.action.TutorialAction and result success`

Following screen is being generated by returning an empty String.

[image]

Comment: nice explanation. so in that case what can i do to overcome this problem? thanks

Comment: Try returning hard-coded value matching your result, something like `return "success";`

Comment: thanks. i tried just now your approach. but it didn't work. what can i do.

Comment: Could you try returning some result name which is not in your struts configuration?

Comment: The original code was returning a non-empty string already; I suspect the complete error was not pasted. It sounds more like a startup issue.

Comment: @JamesJithin i changed the returned string , but still showing same  error.

Comment: @DaveNewton this is the entire error that is showing on browser: HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action org.name.action.TutorialAction and result

**type** Status report

**message** No result defined for action org.name.action.TutorialAction and result

**description** The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.64

Comment: @user5005768 Are you sure you're redeploying and/or restarting the container correctly? I don't yet see how this error message could come from the code you show. Maybe post the example to github so someone can try running it.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks. i'll try it too on github. as a beginner, i don't understand "redeploying and/or restarting the container correctly?"  are talking about web deployment assembly?

Comment: @user5005768, after a change in our project files, what we do about redeploying is first, go to Project>Clean, choose your project and go with a clean and on from the `Servers` view, right click on the server and say restart.

Comment: @JamesJithin during cleaning the project this error was occurred : **Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'Struts2Starter'.
Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/Java8}
Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/Java8}**  what can i do now.thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is another file "commons-lang3xxx.jar", add this file and run it again.